# Change version of npm package automatically each commit to Git

Tags: git, npm, visual-studio-code

I want to run npm version patch after each push (I'm working with vs code).
after checking, there is no such hook as "post-push"
when trying to set this for post-commit,
the npm version runs over and over again, (`package.json` keep changing)

```
echo 'post commit start'
git fetch && npm version --commit-hooks false patch
echo 'post commit end'
```

also: I'm still not sure how to push the tags using the hooks. (`git push --tags`)

**EDIT:**

also tried the following and nothing happens:

1. `nano .git/hooks/post-receive`
2. file content: `git fetch &&  npm version patch && git push --tags`
3. `chmod ug+x .git/hooks/post-receive`
4. changed a file
5. `git commit -m 'test hooks' --all && git push`
6. nothing happens

Comment: Hello. Did you try searching [online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=update+npm+version+on+git+tag+site%3Astackoverflow.com%2F) about this? I found some answers which could suit you.

Comment: You can use [`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive), doesn't it suit you?

Comment: @Maroun - please see question Edit